# Am I designing my Symfony Entities the right way?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a generic Entity called "Product" that has some simple fields such as Name, Description, and Price. I'd like to use this as a base Entity so that I can create other Entities based on this Product Entity that have the exact same fields. I could easily copy the entire Entity Class and Repository files and rename them to Product1, Product1Repository, etc. but I feel that this duplicates a lot of code. I definitely need to work on a copy of the Entity, adding another property/column to my database design won't work with what I'm trying to do. What would be the best way to extend or inherit this class so that Product2, Product3, and ProductN classes can exist as barebones classes that just inherit everything from Product1 and also have a corresponding Doctrine Repository? What would I need to do to accomplish this? Here's the code I have so far:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $price;


//Getters and setters here...
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to be very careful when going down this road.  Doctrine has some solutions but none (in my opinion) work well.  PHP traits might help a bit with reducing duplicate code.  Take a good hard look at exactly what functionality your app will need.  And then see if there is a fundamentally different approach you can try. Otherwise try to keep things as simple as possible.  In the grand scheme of things, even having several dozen almost identical entities and repos will end up being a fairly minor part of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make your base Entity Product as abstract? Then all your other Products can just extend it?

Abstract:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
abstract class Product
{
```

Product1:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=Product1Repository::class)
 */
class Product1 extends Product
{
```

Comment: This totally worked and simply solved the problem! I was not aware this was possible in Symfony-based entities! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could check [Class Table Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) from Doctrine docs.

Basically you create your base Entity with all the fields that are common to sub-entities, then you create a discriminator column and you map the values this column can have, which will map to your sub-entities.

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
* @Entity
* @InheritanceType("JOINED")
* @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
* @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
*/
class Person
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Employee extends Person
{
    // ...
}
```

In this way you'll have a table Person with a column named "discr" and all the other fields you declarated; and a table called Employee with Person.id as Primary Key and Foreign key from Person, plus all the fields you declarated in "Employee" entity.